# Automate timeout handling (wait and refresh) in watir

Tags: ruby, timeout, wait, watir-webdriver, rescue

I have always learned that good coding means: do not repeat yourself. But these days I keep repeating myself, in an attempt to let my scrapers handle timeout errors.

For every link or button that I click, i add a rescue Exception => e and refresh the page.

For example

```
browser.link(:xpath, "//tr[@class='pager'][1]/td/a").when_present.click
```

turns into

```
begin
  browser.link(:xpath, "//tr[@class='pager'][1]/td/a").wait_until_present
  browser.link(:xpath, "//tr[@class='pager'][1]/td/a").click
rescue Exception => e
  sleep (10)
  puts "timed out, let's refresh"
  browser.refresh
end
```

Perhaps there is a cleaner, non-repetitive solution. I've tried manipulating the Watir::wait but I could not get that to work..

```
class Watir::Wait
  alias_method :__do_wait, :wait_until
  def wait_until
    begin
      __do_wait{ yield }
    rescue Exception => e
      puts "timed out. let's refresh"
      $browser.refresh
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are combining `wait_until_present` with a page refresh? Watir's wait methods are waiting for a element that is assumed to be asynchronously loaded (ie does not require a page refresh). If your element needs a page refresh to be updated, then the `wait_until_present` will always fail and just consume time.

Comment: I use wait_until_present as a way not to waste excess time in waiting for an element to appear (vice versa `sleep(x)`) for example. The problem that keeps appearing in a few scrapes i try to run, is a timeout that sometimes appears. I guess you're right that in those cases I am waiting too long because I use wait_until_present, but that's not a big problem at the moment.

Comment: What is supposed to happen after the browser refresh? Are you supposed to retry clicking the link or just continue on with the script? Currently, your code appears to be attempting the later. However, I would have guessed you wanted the former (ie try, refresh, try again, repeat)

Comment: Yes, the latter would be better but in some cases impossible (for example, in the case of an online database that automatically goes to the first page on a refresh) so I try to make it such that the code just continues on to the next iteration without the scraper getting stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for my enlish, i'm french.... lol this script allows to refresh browser without to skip a step, for exemple when you have to login, you can't skip a step..... and if you have a website with too many connexion with a low bandwhith.....

I think that seeb would do this :

```
module Watir

class WhenPresentDecorator
def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
  unless @element.respond_to?(m)
    raise NoMethodError, "undefined method `#{m}' for #{@element.inspect}:#   {@element.class}"
  end

  begin
    while !@element.present? 
     sleep(10)
    puts "timed out, let's refresh"
    @element.browser.refresh
    end
   rescue

   else
     @element.__send__(m, *args, &block)
   end
      end
     end # WhenPresentDecorator  
   end
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your requirements correctly, I think you want to override the `method_missing` handling of the WhenPresentDecorator.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

module Watir
  class WhenPresentDecorator
    def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
      unless @element.respond_to?(m)
        raise NoMethodError, "undefined method `#{m}' for #{@element.inspect}:#{@element.class}"
      end

      begin
        Watir::Wait.until(@timeout, @message) { @element.present? }
      rescue
        sleep(10)
        puts "timed out, let's refresh"
        @element.browser.refresh
      else
        @element.__send__(m, *args, &block)
      end
    end
  end # WhenPresentDecorator  
end
```

With this monkey patch, `when_present` will wait for the element to be present. If the element is present, it will perform the action (ie click in your example). If the element is not present, it will catch the exception, ignore it, refresh the page and continue on to the next statement.

For example, given the following page that has a div tag that shows the time of page load:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function startTime()
      {
        var today=new Date();
        var h=today.getHours();
        var m=today.getMinutes();
        var s=today.getSeconds();
        document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="startTime()">
    <div id="txt"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can see that no exception occurs when accessing an element (link) that does exist. As well, the page refreshes after trying to find that element.

```
puts browser.div(:id => 'txt').text  
#=> "22:48:25"

browser.link(:id => 'asdf').when_present.click
#=> "timed out, let's refresh"

puts browser.div(:id => 'txt').text
#=> "22:48:36"
```

Comment: I'm afraid it doesnt seem to work. I ended up with a `'rescue in rbuf_fill': Timeout::Error` including a 'method missing' for         `@element.__send__(m, *args, &block)`

Comment: Do you get that exception when using the sample page above or against your actual application?

Comment: on my own, actual, application.

Comment: Yes it does: 15.47.36 | timed out, let's refresh | 15.48.16

Comment: I am not sure why it would not work with your application then. The code is not doing anything fancy at all.